# PyQT GUI Testing

Tags: python, testing, pyqt

Does anyone know of a automated GUI testing package for that works with PyQT besides Squish?  Nothing against Squish I am just looking for other packages.  It would be cool if there were an open source package.  I am doing my testing under Linux.

Comment: Y'know, I have a whole book on "Scripted GUI Testing with Ruby" (http://pragprog.com/titles/idgtr/scripted-gui-testing-with-ruby) that I got from a Ruby User Group meeting, but I've never read it so find out what kind of tools they use.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this testing?

Comment: I'm very curious to know the final solution you used~

Comment: We bought Squish.  It works well and they are responsive but I love the open source python testing community and wanted to go there first.

Comment: The Python wiki has some info on this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/GUI_Testing Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like PyQT4 includes a QtTest object that can be used for unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

[WATSUP](http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html) has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, WATSUP looks interesting for Windows GUI testing.  Unfortunately I need Linux PyQT GUI testing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use pyunit in conjunction with PyQT.

http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: While pyunit (called unittest in stdlib) is good for normal unit testing it doesn't handle GUI testing.

Comment: @PaulHildebrandt At the time of writing Python unittest works with PyQt, please see [this article](http://johnnado.com/pyqt-qtest-example/). Kind Regards, Tord

Comment: I am the author of "this article." I merged the `johnnado.com` / `voom.net` blog article into the example code https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample to make a unified open source project. Contributors wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[py.test](https://pytest.org) with the [pytest-qt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-qt) plugin**. There's a simple example of how it can be used [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/#pytest-qt)

Another alternative is to use **the built-in [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module together with [QtTest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html)** (parts of QtTest has been built into PyQt). A longer example is given in [**this article**](http://johnnado.com/pyqt-qtest-example/)

All of this is free and open source :)

Comment: Comparing these two alternatives the first combination gives you more features and a nicer API, while the second has the advantage of not adding more dependencies

Comment: I am the author of "this article." I merged the `johnnado.com` / `voom.net` blog article into the example code https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample to make a unified open source project. Contributors wanted!